# how to move images from one folder to another in gallery

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-image, android-imagebutton

I created an image gallery app.*I am able to select images using my app and come back to activity which displays all folders but not able to move them using my app.* 
I want to select multiple images, click on *buttoncut* and come back to activity which displays all folders(ImageGallery.java). Now , I want to select a folder and paste all the selected images in that folder .How can I achieve this ?

ImageGallery.java **(activity which displays all folders)**

```
public class ImageGallery extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<Model_images> al_images = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean boolean_folder;
    Adapter_PhotosFolder obj_adapter;
    GridView gv_folder;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;
    int int_position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        gv_folder = (GridView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        obj_adapter = new Adapter_PhotosFolder(this,al_images,int_position);
        gv_folder.setAdapter(obj_adapter);

        final ImageButton buttonpaste = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonpaste);
        buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final ImageButton buttoncut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        gv_folder.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value",i);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        gv_folder.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,final int i, long l) {
                for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++)
                    adapterView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                // change the background color of the selected element
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttoncut.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(View view){
                                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                        });
                button2.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(View view){
                                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                        });
                button3.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageGallery.this);
                                builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete it ?");
                                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                        "Yes",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                File file = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(i));
                                                file.delete();
                                                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ImageGallery.this,new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                                                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                al_images.remove(i);
                                                obj_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });

                                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                        "No",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                alert11.show();
                            }
                        });

                return true;
            }
        });

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ImageGallery.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale( ImageGallery.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( ImageGallery.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }else {
            Log.e("Else","Else");
            fn_imagespath();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Model_images> fn_imagespath() {
        al_images.clear();

        int int_position = 0;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

        String absolutePathOfImage;
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
            Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));

            for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
                if (al_images.get(i).getStr_folder().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                    boolean_folder = true;
                    int_position = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    boolean_folder = false;
                }
            }


            if (boolean_folder) {

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.addAll(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath());
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                al_images.get(int_position).setAl_imagepath(al_path);

            } else {
                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                Model_images obj_model = new Model_images();
                obj_model.setStr_folder(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                obj_model.setAl_imagepath(al_path);

                al_images.add(obj_model);

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("FOLDER", al_images.get(i).getStr_folder());
            for (int j = 0; j < al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().size(); j++) {
                Log.e("FILE", al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().get(j));
            }
        }
        obj_adapter = new Adapter_PhotosFolder(getApplicationContext(),al_images,int_position);
        gv_folder.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
        return al_images;
    }
```

PhotosActivity.java **(Activity which displays images inside a folder)**:

```
import static com.example.dell_1.myapp3.ImageViewer.ImageGallery.al_images;

public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int int_position;
    private GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean boolean_folder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        final ImageButton buttoncut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        final ImageButton buttonpaste = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonpaste);
        buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_images, int_position);
        gridView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("folderPosition", int_position);
                i.putExtra("abc", abc);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                if(mSelected.contains(position)) {
                    mSelected.remove(position);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);// remove item from list
                    // update view (v) state here
                    // eg: remove highlight
                }
                else {
                    mSelected.add(position);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);// add item to list
                    // update view (v) state here
                    // eg: add highlight
                }


                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttoncut.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(View view){
                                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                startActivityB();
                            }

                });
                button2.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(View view){
                                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                startActivityB();

                            }

                        });
                button3.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotosActivity.this);
                                builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete it ?");
                                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                        "Yes",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                adapter.updateUpdater(mSelected);
                                                for(int position=0;position<mSelected.size();position++) {
                                                    al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().remove(position);
                                                }
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });

                                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                        "No",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                alert11.show();
                            }
                        });

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void startActivityB() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PhotosActivity.this,ImageGallery.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Unclear how you let the user select images. With your app? Or how?

Comment: yes, through my app.  I am able to select images using my app but not able to move them using my app. @greenapps

Comment: Then what did you try to move them? And what did you do before to be able to display folders ? Hiw dud you obtain info about image files? How did you obtain those folders? Pretty unclear what you are doing.

Comment: Share some code that would make it easy for us

Comment: I have updated the question @greenapps

Comment: @G.hakim I have added some code

Comment: It looks as if you get all info about folders and files from the media store. You are not scanning the file system yourself. You could have told that at the start of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Move/Copy a file you can use following snippet .

```
 private void copyOrMoveFile(File file, File dir,boolean isCopy) throws IOException {
    File newFile = new File(dir, file.getName());
    FileChannel outChannel = null;
    FileChannel inputChannel = null;
    try {
        outChannel = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();
        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
        inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outChannel);
        inputChannel.close();
        if(!isCopy)
        file.delete();
    } finally {
        if (inputChannel != null) inputChannel.close();
        if (outputChannel != null) outputChannel.close();
    }
}
```

Make sure In case of Cut or Move you have to delete the source file .

Comment: thanks , is file the image which is cut and dir the image which is pasted ?

Comment: dir is destination directory . and file is image to be copy or cut .

Comment: I am , a bit unsure though, whether to put this code in first activity or second, because image to be moved is selected in another activity and destination folder is selected in another activity @ADM

Comment: You have to put this code in an background thread . So its better to create a Utility `AsyncTask` with callbacks.